# не могу воспользоваться внешним жестким диском

Tags: windows

всем привет, возникла проблема. Взял в самолет с собой жесткий диск(250 гб) от компа с линуксом и со всеми данными на нем, при приезде купил внешний бокс для него чтобы подключить жд к ноутбуку(вот бокс https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/bae6daf10a833330/35-vnesnij-boks-dexp-ua003/). При загрузке через биос высвечивается черный экран, проверил жд через EaseUS и стало понятно что все данные стерлись, ладно, восстановил, но как их перекинуть обратно на жд? Захожу в управление жесткими дисками и ничего с ним сделать не могу, ни отформатировать, ни переименовать , что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
на 2-ом фото мой диск без названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая файловая система на внешнем диске?

Comment: @becouse,easeus disk copy пишет `other`, в управлении в винде вообще пустое поле

Comment: Значит он в ext4 скорее всего. Нужна утилита для Windows которая позволяет работать с такими ФС.

Comment: @becouse,спасибо за наводку, попробую тогда пока-что восстановить через r-linux данные